# how to sql sorted and update "SortKey" after delete some "sortkey" in "Sortkey"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

if "simon" in SortKey  "3" and "josef " in SortKey "5" go to finish and retirement, then the ID  number 3, 5 is stay.

but sortkey is deleted

where i want to make rebuild in SortKey with new members with stay in work

Table Name: TblMaster
example Fields:

```
-----------------------
ID    SortKey   Name
-----------------------
1-       1      john
2-       2      steve
3-       3      simon
4-       4      onil
5-       5      josef
6-       6      mohamed
7-       7      ebraham
-----------------------
```

need to change like

```
-----------------------
ID      SortKey     Name
-----------------------
1-       1      john
2-       2      steve
3-              simon
4-       3      onil
5-              josef
6-       4      mohamed
7-       5      ebraham
-----------------------
```

we talk about 5000 employees
how can update all SortKey with new sorted

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you sort by `SortKey` and just filter out the retired/terminated employees in your `WHERE` clause (how do you indicate that someone has retired? Just by updating `SortKey` on their record?), everyone will still be sorted correctly. `SortKey` does not need to be contiguous.

Comment: because it is a system for sortkey in degree with judge in stay at work

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what that means.

Comment: We are talking about the ranking of senior members of the company
Consists of 7 degrees
Each degree has its own order
A member may retire or resign

Members who are in actual work are ranked according to seniority rather than who went out

Do you understand what I mean now?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one approach is though two updates.  First we NULL the appropriate `SortKey's` and then we create the new key via `Row_Number()` (excluding the NULL `SortKey's`)

**Example**

```
Update YourTable set SortKey=null where ID in (3,5)  -- Or whatever desired condition

;with cte as (
     Select *
            ,NewKey = Row_Number() over (Order By SortKey) 
      From  YourTable
      Where SortKey is not null
)
Update cte Set SortKey=NewKey
```

**The Updated Table**

```
ID  SortKey Name
1   1       john
2   2       steve
3   NULL    simon
4   3       onil
5   NULL    josef
6   4       mohamed
7   5       ebraham
```